# How do I save R code using code in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, autosave

I am looking for a way to 'auto save' my code each time i run it.  I figure the best way to achieve this would be to write code in my models which will overwrite and save the file which is open. I have been experimenting with:

```
rstudioapi::documentSave(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$id)
```

However, I have not had any success.

Comment: There is an option in Rstudio to "Always save R scripts before sourcing". Does this do what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning All,

I worked out the issue.  The model I am working on generates tables, which are produced with View(). This means when the code is finished running the script is not the tab displayed.

```
documentSave()
```

Will only save the script which is open.  Therefore, it is advised that you should consider using

```
documentSaveAll()
```

Which will save all tabs open.